# Typechecking Components that implement an Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, components, typechecking

In Angular, I want to specify the type for a component that implements a certain interface that I pass into a class.

Example:
Class A has this signature

```
class A {
  constructor(public component: ?) {}
}
```

Then we declare an interface I

```
export interface I<T> {
  setData(data: T): void;
}
```

The component B implements the interface I

```
class B implements I<string> {
  setData(data: string) { ... }
}
```

Now the problem is that not only component B implements I, but also component C, D and E. Furthermore class A should be able to process the components B,C,D and E, i.e. all components that implement interface I.
Can I specify in class A that the component type is any component that implements interface I? My solution right now is

```
component: any
```

But I would like to specify that it can be any with the restriction that it implements I.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Does `component: I` not work?

Comment: Maybe it works. The problem is when I do this I get the following error that I don't know how to resolve: 

```Property 'setData' is missing in type 'typeof B' but required in type 'I<any>'.```
`Even though the method is overriden in B. Any ideas?

Comment: This error occurs when I try: ```new A(B)```

Comment: The ```?``` should be replaced with any and it would work. I am not injecting interfaces, but injecting components that implement a specific interface I. I wrote ```?``` because I don't know how to specify the type of this component aside from 'any'. And I can't say it is of type 'B', because it should be a generic component however implementing the specific interface I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
class A {
  constructor(public component: new (...args: any[]) => I<any>)
}
```